# Laravel DB log time metrics

Tags: database, laravel, logging, time

In Laravel there is an option to enable db query logging. In array it returns query, bindings and time. Question is is time in microseconds?

Comment: it's calculated using the microtime function, what you get is a milliseconds time value.look its implementation here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/da5bdc94574d796b136d607365619506ca67ac50/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php#L592

Comment: at the start of query execution you can use $start = microtime(true); and after executing $end = microtime(true) - $start;
to get query execution time

Answer (score 0):

For view all metrics query I use this lib  [barryvdh/laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) in Dev mode.